# How can you define a common Medium in a custom Fluid.System?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am designing a set of custom components for fluid system modelling. As there will only be one medium throughout the model, I want to be able to define that medium in one place. The `system` component we need for most Modelica.Fluid systems anyway seems like a good place.

I have tried the following MWE, but I'm running into problems with class lookup that I don't know how to avoid.
Using current OpenModelica, when checking the `CommonMediaClosedVolume`, I'm getting an error

> Class name 'system.CommonMedium' was found via a component (only component and function call names may be accessed in this way).

I noticed that there is a `Fluid.System.Medium` defined which I thought could serve a similar purpose, but it's not visible for changing in the parameter dialog in OMEdit (Although it has a `choicesAllMatching` annotation -- an OM bug?), and it does not seem to get used anywhere else. In any case, it shows the same lookup error message.

Question:

- How can I define a default class (derived from `PartialMedium`) in `TweakedSystem` so that I can extend my models to pick that up by default, and so that I can select the desired medium in a `TweakedSystem` instance `system`?

```
package CommonMediaDefinition
 
  model TweakedSystem "Extended system featuring a common media definition"
    extends Modelica.Fluid.System(Medium = CommonMedium);
    replaceable package CommonMedium = Modelica.Media.Air.DryAirNasa constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium annotation(
       choicesAllMatching = true);
    annotation(
      defaultComponentName = "system",
      defaultComponentPrefixes = "inner");
  end TweakedSystem;

  model CommonMediaClosedVolume "ClosedVolume with a default Medium defined in system"
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume;
    // Want to define a Medium default choice that is defined in system (a TweakedSystem instance)
    redeclare replaceable package Medium = system.CommonMedium;
    // Errors with Class name 'system.CommonMedium' was found via a component (only component and function call names may be accessed in this way).
  end CommonMediaClosedVolume;

  model SimulationModel
  inner TweakedSystem system 
    annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, -56}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  CommonMediaClosedVolume commonMediaClosedVolume(V = 1)
    annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  end SimulationModel;

end CommonMediaDefinition;
```

*Edit: It seems that this way I envisioned propagating a class is not allowed in Modelica: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24209596/599884*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to add the medium to the system. Maybe someone else knows how to do so.

But you could achieve a global media definition by defining an `inner package` for your single medium at top of your simulation model. The modified components have an `outer package` defined.

At the end the usage is quite similar to your approach. Instead of adding just a modified System, you have to use the original System and additionally extend a base model which provides the inner Medium package.

Unfortunately this method makes some troubles. In Dymola 2022x it works fine *(unless you activate pedantic mode, which gives an error due to problems in the medium Modelica.Media.Air.DryAirNasa...)*.
But in OpenModelica 1.18.1 you have to switch to the "Old Frontend", as translation fails otherwise. And you have to define a non-partial medium in the components. I am not sure if this will make troubles later...

```
package CommonMediaDefinition

  partial model CommonMediumSelector "Extend to inherit CommonMedium parameter"
    inner replaceable package CommonMedium = Modelica.Media.Air.DryAirNasa
       constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium
       annotation (choicesAllMatching = true);
  end CommonMediumSelector;

  model CommonMediaClosedVolume "ClosedVolume with Medium defined via outer CommonMedium"
    // I would use this in Dymola, to ensure that a proper medium is selected, but it does not
    // work in OpenModelica...
    // outer replaceable package CommonMedium = Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;
    // ... hence we have to use this: 
    outer replaceable package CommonMedium = Modelica.Media.Air.DryAirNasa;
    extends Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume(redeclare final package Medium=CommonMedium);
  end CommonMediaClosedVolume;

  model SimulationModel
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-90,70},{-70,90}})));
    extends CommonMediumSelector(redeclare package CommonMedium = Modelica.Media.Air.DryAirNasa);
    CommonMediaClosedVolume commonMediaClosedVolume(V=1) 
      annotation (Placement(visible=true, transformation(origin={0,-20}, extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}}, rotation=0)));
  end SimulationModel;

  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end CommonMediaDefinition;
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, that could also be a useful approach. I'll have to tinker a bit...

Comment: It seems the originally proposed way is not legal in Modelica (see edit I made to the question), so this is probably the best we can do to work around that language limitation.